# How to make a UIView's height not restricted in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have a `UIView` that has a height of 40. But I have a `UILabel` inside of that that could be one line or multiple. How do I make the `UIView` resize depending on that? I am open to doing this in Swift if I need to but if there is a way in Interface Builder that would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add top, left, right , bottom constraints via IB for your label and set number of lines to 0

[image]

2. Add flexible height for your container view ( add height constraint and change it to be Greater then or equal)
   [image]
3. Now, if you set long test - it will automatically extend container view :

[image]